# Is this a function or vector space?

Tags: mathematical-economics, preferences

I want to make a function that states consumer $i's$ consumption $C_i$  in a shared bundle $X^n$ $\subset$ $\mathbb R^n$ depends on their preferences. That is, something like $C_i(\succeq_i)$.

Since $\succeq_i$ is a binary relator that does not take any value, would I denote this as a vector space $C_i(X^n,\succeq_i)$?

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean with "a function that states consumer $i$'s consumption in a shared bundle". Does $X^n$ vary? What is the output of $C_i$ (a set or an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or an element of $X^n$?) What restrictions do you impose on $\succeq_i$?

Comment: Vector spaces need vector operations like vector addition and scalar multiplication. These make little sense here.

Comment: It seems you mean $C_i \in X^n$, i.e. the compsumption will be a set of "consumed" quantities. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

A *function* or *mapping* in mathematics requires that there are **two sets** on which the function is defined.

The so-called **classical  definition of function** (ascribed to Dirichlet)  is the following:

> **Definition.** Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever. A *function* $f$ is a **rule** that associates to each element of $A$ a **unique** element of $B$.

The set $A$ is called the *domain* of $f$, and the set of the values of $f$ is called the *range* of $f$.
The concept of rule is left undefinied.

In your example you have a set, $X^n\subset R^n$, as range, and a relation $\succeq_i$ as domain.

A *relation* in set theory is **defined as a set**, a set of ordered pairs:

> **Definition.** A **relation** on a set $A$ is a subset $C$ of the cartesian product $A\times A$.

It is, in some way, a concept more general than that of function (see for instance Munkres, *Topology*).

So,  in principle, from a formal point of view,  you can define a function from $\succeq_i$ to $X^n$, that is a function that assigns an element of $X^n$ to each pair that forms the set $\succeq_i$.

But what does it mean from an economic point of view? I think, nothing. This way you associate to each pair that forms the $\succeq_i$ set, a bundle of consumption of the consumer $i$. It seems to me meanigless.

Instead, you can consider the set of **all possible** preferences $\succeq_i$, that is a set of sets, and assign to each set of preferences a commodity bundle $X_i$. That is, you have to take as domain not   $\succeq_i$, but $\succeq_i$, $i=1,...,n,...$, for instance. Maybe it makes sense. But I wonder if it can be useful, I don't know.

As for your second question, $C_i(X^n, \succeq_i)$ cannot be viewed as a vector space. Vector space needs two operations, scalar multiplication and addition of vectors, $\succeq_i$ is not any of them.

Anyway, it is not clear what you mean by  $C_i(X^n, \succeq_i)$: a set? a function?

Comment: How can you answer a question which you yourself admit you don't understand? You are asking the right questions at the end!

Comment: I understand very well the question. To answer is sufficient to know the definition of vector space. In both cases, that is if the notation indicates a vector space or a function, it cannot represent a vector space, it is obviuosly wrong to say that can be a vector space, in any case. But I asked my question because also the notation is wrong if one wants to denote a vector space. Maybe is correct in case it denotes a function. And I asked what was the idea in writing this strange notation, in order to understand the reason of the mistake.